# upgraded to jquery 1.4.1 & now getting parse error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have tried upgrading from  jQuery 1.2.6 to 1.4.1.
A JSON query is now failing with error : "parseerror, invalid label"

I have simplified the code to bare minimum.

```
var jsonUrl = "process_01.php";
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url:  jsonUrl,   
 data: "var=myVar",        
 dataType: "json",    
 beforeSend: function(msg) {
 },
 success: function(msg) {
 },
 error: function (msg, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   alert("an error has occured (" + textStatus + " " + errorThrown +")" );
   }
});
return false;
}
```

Output of php program is 
{"foo":"bar","IsTrue":"true"}

I can see this in firebug

Comment: Are you double-extra-sure that your returned JSON is legit?  Like, there are no stray commas or anything?

Comment: Hmm, actually firebug does not recognize it as JSON (missing extra JSON tab). Actually the old version is not recognized as JSON either!
However it pass JSLint.  BTW, it fails in both IE & Mozilla.

Comment: JQuery got a lot stricter with its parser in 1.4 (see http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/15/jquery-1-4-and-malformed-json/). Your JSON looks OK to me, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your content type is set to application/json.

Also look at [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/99-JSON-Minor-But-VERY-Important-Detail-Creating-Syntax-Error-Invalid-Label.htm), looks similar to your problem.

Comment: It looks like my php script was throwing out a blank line before the header.

Answer (score 0):

There should be single quotes around the values sent. Like [this guy](http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3982918.htm) did.

Comment: tried with both single & double quotes. same result... I find it odd that firebug does not recognize this a JSON...

$returnArray = $arr = array("foo" => "bar", "isTrue" => "true");
echo json_encode($returnArray);

Can someone else try this?

Comment: I found http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/5104 which seems to say that json_encode isn't "valid" enough. Instead they implemented a custom function `array_to_json` as seen in http://dev.jqueryui.com/browser/trunk/demos/autocomplete/search.php?rev=3749#L636. I still can't figure out exactly what makes it invalid though.

Comment: @matschaffer: That should be it.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone else who stumbles across this, the original poster said he wasn't sending out the header as application/json. In my case I ran into trouble parsing quoted apostrophes inside a double quoted string like this:

`{"description": "An invalid person\'s JSON"}`

Looks like 1.3.2 took this, but 1.4.1 rejects it. Guess I'll have to find a more graceful approach to escaping on the server side. See http://jsbin.com/oveci3 for what I used for reference.